# Kafka Binders for Spring Cloud not rolling back with Transactional

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to send messages to two separate topics in Kafka via Spring Cloud in a transaction. When throwing an exception between the first and second messages, the first message still appears in the consumer for the first topic, showing that the messages aren't being rolled back. Here is my code:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class KafkaChannelTester implements CommandLineRunner {

    ChannelHolder channelHolder;
    MessageChannel messageChannel1;
    MessageChannel messageChannel2;

    public KafkaChannelTester(ChannelHolder channelHolder) {
        this.channelHolder = channelHolder;
        this.messageChannel1 = channelHolder.messageChannel1();
        this.messageChannel2 = channelHolder.messageChannel2();
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        transactionFail();
    }


    public void throwException(){ throw new RuntimeException();}

    @Transactional
    public void transactionFail(){
        Message<String> message1 = MessageBuilder
            .withPayload("Test-transaction-fail-"+ LocalDateTime.now())
            .build();
        Message<String> message2 = MessageBuilder
            .withPayload("Test-transaction-fail-"+ LocalDateTime.now())
            .build();
        messageChannel1.send(message1);
        throwException();
        messageChannel2.send(message2);
    }
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(BinderFactory binders) {
        ProducerFactory<byte[], byte[]> pf = ((KafkaMessageChannelBinder) binders.getBinder(null,
            MessageChannel.class)).getTransactionalProducerFactory();
        System.out.println(pf.transactionCapable());
        System.out.println(pf.getTransactionIdPrefix());
        KafkaTransactionManager tm = new KafkaTransactionManager<>(pf);
        return tm;
    }
}
```

The application.yml contailns the following:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        cloud-producer-1:
          destination:
            peter.cloud.test.1
        cloud-producer-2:
          destination:
            peter.cloud.test.2
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers:
            - testkbroker:9092
          transaction:
            transaction-id-prefix: transaction-1-
            producer:
              configuration:
                enable.idempotence: true
                retries: 1
                acks: all
```

The print statements in transactionManager confirm that the producer factory does have a transaction id prefix, and is transaction capable. What can I do to get transactions working?

Answer (score 0):

Records are always written to the log, even if they are rolled back. By default, consumers will see rolled back records, you have to set the consumer property `isolation.level` to `read_committed` to avoid getting rolled back records.

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs_isolation.level

Comment: Even with the isolation level being set to read_committed, the messages are still showing up.

Comment: Where are you calling `transactionFail()` from? If you are calling from the `CommandLineRunner.run()` method, you are bypassing the transaction interceptor. You need to move the method to a different bean so the method can be intercepted to start the transaction. Or, start the transaction manually with a `TransactionTemplate`. When the messages arrive at the `KafkaProducerMessageHandler`, if there is no existing transaction, the handler does each send in a local transaction which is committed.

Comment: I was calling it from CommandLineRunner.run(). It started working as a transaction when I took that out and ran CommandLineRunner.run() in a different class. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Run the transactional method from a different class. CommandLineRunner.run() bypasses the transaction interceptor if the "run" method and the "Transactional" annotated method are in the same class, preventing the transactional method from being run as a transaction.